# Based on user's choice for CharAt, how can I add the rest of the sentence?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have this simple function, where user can type a sentence and it will capitalze one letter, based on user's choice. For example if user choose to capitalize first letter for sentence "hey" he would write `titleCase("hey", 0)` but it will only return that one capitalized letter instead of the whole "Hey" word. It's because I have splited it into array, but how can I return the whole word, not only the capitalized one? My code

```
function titleCase(str, userChoice) {
var string = str;
var split = string.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
split[i] = split[i].charAt(userChoice).toUpperCase(); + split[i].slice(0);
}
console.log (split.join(" "));
}

titleCase();
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

Just capitalize the index user selected and then return the string.

```js
function titleCase(str, userChoice) {
  var string = str;
  var split = string.split("");

  split[userChoice] = split[userChoice].toUpperCase();
  return (split.join(''));
}

console.log(titleCase('hey', 0))
```

Issue I noticed in  your code:

`string.split(" ");` -> this will split the string at space but your string is one word so it is never split.

Comment: There are better versions of the code I have posted, this one is just for reference of logic

Comment: yeah, this makes sense now. I just made the problem more complicated than it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function titleCase(str, userChoice) {
  var str = str;
  var split = str.split(" ");
  split[userChoice] = capitalize(split[userChoice]);
  return split.join(" ");
}

function capitalize(s) {
  return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substr(1, s.length - 1)
}

console.log(titleCase('hello world', 0));
console.log(titleCase('hello world', 1));
```